# How are websites automatically zoomed out when browsed by mobile phones?

Tags: web, mobile-phones, screen-resolution

In my case I made the div width `500px`,

but it automatically zoomed out when browsed in a mobilephone

How's the magic done exactly,is it device specific?

Comment: I would imagine this is device specific, but if I were going to do it, I'd treat the page like an image and scale it so that it's only a fraction of it's regular width but proportionally the same.

Comment: Anyone knows what if you try to view an image 1280px on mobile phones? Can't test it myself for now

Comment: **A LOT has changed in in this area in the >3 years since this question was asked**.  Responsive design is now commonplace and mobile browsers are standardizing on a "meta viewport" instruction in the page's head.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to try something like this in the head of the html page:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
```

For more info see here:
http://davidbcalhoun.com/2010/viewport-metatag

Answer (score 2):

**Edit: the answer below no longer reflects current normal practice. There is now a fairly well established standard called the meta viewport which controls how the page is scaled on mobile. In the absence of this, sites are deemed "not mobile friendly" and mobile browsers show the page at typical desktop width, zoomed out to show full width.**

---

It is browser specific.

It's even a configurable option in most mobile browsers (eg Android, Nokia S60, Opera Mini).  I prefer to have it turned off, so that pages open with normal 100% zoom (and if it's cut off, I just scroll).

Some people prefer to see the whole page width at once even if the text is too small to read, then double-tap to zoom up after that.

The browser typically calculates the total width of the page first.  In this calculation any flexible-width element is taken to be the minimum width which can fit all its children.  If this is less or equal to the width of the browser window no scaling is done, but if it's greater, the browser sets this as the virtual page width and, if the user has turned this option on, scales everything down (like zooming out in a modern desktop browser) so that that minimum width of the page occupies the width of the browser window.

Answer (score 0):

The browser do whatever it wants to. Since mobile phones have a small screen probably this browser zoomed out to be more pleasant to look the page.

Comment: You mean it's browser specific,and there's no standard for this?

Comment: The standard is to use 500px, but this browser didn't follow.